# jQuery trigger click to show errors is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jquery tabs login and sign up I need when the registration page has errors to trigger the registration page to open but the default first page is login.

```html
<div class="auth-buttons" >
    <a class="btn" id="btn-login">Login</a>
    <a class="btn" id="btn-register">Register</a>
</div>

<div id="lgn" class="btns">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login')}}" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<div id="reg" class="btns">
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register')}}" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<script>
    $('#reg').hide();

    $('#btn-login').click(function(){
        $('#reg').hide();
        $('#lgn').show();
    });

    $('#btn-register').click(function(){
        $('#lgn').hide();
        $('#reg').show();
    });
</script>
```

I have tried this script but its not working. When register has errors it displays the errors, but it goes back to login first.

```html
<script>

    $(function() {
        let hasErrors = document.getElementsByClassName('errorClass').length > 0;

        if(hasErrors)
        {
            $('#btn-register').trigger('click');
        }

    });

</script>
```

Comment: So when you submit it has issues? So maybe you should add code to determine what form to display from the serverside,

Comment: no when  i want to display registration errors

Comment: so show it and do not call the code that hides it

Comment: am still not understanding can you please illustrate with code